# Which is the Virtual Key in Mac for the Eject Key

Tags: macos, keyboard

I would like to remap the Mac Eject Key into Insert, in particular for emulating Ctrl+Insert, Alt+Insert, Shift+Insert and other common key combinations in Windows applications.

Which is the Virtual Key code for the Eject Key?  I found some virtual key tables, but for some reason the Eject Key is never included.

Comment: In your program or on your computer? What language are you using?

Comment: My first use will be to try if I can put that virtual key in CoRD emulation program tables, as this is a need related to Windows programs accessed via CoRD.  If that does not work, then I will probably try something with Objective C or C++ (I suppose that the Carbon framework will be involved).

Answer (score 1):

Q: Which is the Virtual Key in Mac for the Eject Key?

A: None.

With reference to [HID Usage Tables for Universal Serial Bus](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/hut1_2.pdf), Eject is not a keypress but actually a HID Usage - a One Shot Control from the Consumer Usage Page.

> **3.4.1.4 One Shot Control (OSC)**
> A One Shot Control is a push button that triggers a single event or action. A One Shot Control is encoded into a 1-bit
> value and declared as a Relative, Preferred, Main item with a Logical Minimum and Logical Maximum of 0 and 1,
> respectively. A 0 to 1 transition initiates an event. Nothing occurs on a 1 to 0 transition but it is required before another
> event can occur. An example is degauss.

On the Consumer Usage Page (0x0C) the Eject Usage ID is defined as:

| Usage ID | Usage Name | Usage Types | Section |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B8 | Eject | OSC | 15.7 |

If you were wanting to fake an Eject keypress from a USB HID-capable Arduino, such as the Leonardo, you could do so with the following code which sends a Control-Shift-Eject to lock the screen...

```cpp
// NicoHood's HID-Project
#include "HID-Project.h"

void setup() {
  // Make pin 2 an input and turn on the pull-up resistor
  // so it goes high unless connected to ground:
  pinMode(2, INPUT_PULLUP);

  Keyboard.begin();

  // Sends a clean report to the host.
  // This is important on any Arduino type.
  Consumer.begin();
}

void loop() {
  // Control-Shift-Eject locks the screen
  if (digitalRead(2) == LOW) {
    Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_CTRL);
    Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_SHIFT);

    // This is a One Shot Command so doesn't need a "release"
    Consumer.write(HID_CONSUMER_EJECT);

    // Debounce
    delay(100);
    while (digitalRead(2) == LOW)
      delay(100);

    // Release Control-Shift keys
    Keyboard.releaseAll();
  }
}
```

As to reacting to an Eject keypress from Windows, unless it's raised as one of the Media Control-related WM_ events I expect you'll have to write a USB HID/ACPI driver that detects and raises the OSC itself.

There is [Sample buttons in ACPI for device running Windows 10 desktop editions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/acpi-button-device#sample-buttons-in-acpi-for-device-running-windows-10-desktop-editions) which demonstrates capturing some of the other OSCs from the Consumer page (such as Volume Increments/Decrements), you could probably expand upon this to include Eject.

Sorry I can't be of more help there, but hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I know that question has been made years ago, but maybe some people are still looking for that answer and will end up finding that question so...

Line 1805 of `VoodooPS2Keyboard.cpp` from **VoodooPS2Controller** by RehabMan says that the virtual key on Mac for the Eject Key is **`0x92`**.

Reference:

https://github.com/RehabMan/OS-X-Voodoo-PS2-Controller/blob/master/VoodooPS2Keyboard/VoodooPS2Keyboard.cpp