# SOLVED: The Mac Magic Keyboard Eject key is easily assignable

Tags: macos, keyboard, key-bindings

There have been so many discussions over the years about this and I don't mean to rehash any of it. But there is some information floating around that's not correct. Or if I'm wrong, please correct me.

## EDIT: SOLUTION

I found it. The Magic Keyboard `Eject` key (⏏) is easily reachable. I can assign it to be `forward delete` or absolutely any key. It's simple. But the instructions are hard to find.

Resource: https://verityj.github.io/2023/06/17/eject.html

### Original note:

My conclusion: Eject key is not accessible. It is not part of the standard keybindings in `/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Resources/StandardKeyBinding.dict`

(Eject key is [an HID usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65596091/21830654)).

But I did try to get to it inside `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` Is there anything else I could try? (Without having to resort to Karabiner.)

In my `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` I ended up commenting out the following:

```
/* Eject symbols below is not an eject key and does not work: */

    "\UF804" = "deleteForward:";
        /* eject symbol? ⏏ as forward delete - does not work */
        /* from http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/APPLE/CORPCHAR.TXT */
        /* "Keyboard-0x8C" */
        /* "0x8C 0x23CF # EJECT SYMBOL # Unicode 4.0 and later, Mac OS X only" */
        /* from https://unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/APPLE/KEYBOARD.TXT */
    
   "\U23CF" = "deleteForward:";
        /* eject symbol? ⏏ as forward delete - does not work */
```

But interestingly, in Xcode under key bindings the forward delete changed to show two different Eject symbols:

[Xcode shortcut screenshot for delete forward](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrZXg.png)

Am I correct to assume that the two unicodes above are actually for the Eject symbol and not a keyboard key?

Thank you everyone, I am asking so I can understand what is going on with that key.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. The Magic Keyboard `Eject` key (⏏) is easily reachable. I can assign it to be `forward delete` or absolutely any key. It's simple. But the instructions are hard to find.

Resource: https://verityj.github.io/2023/06/17/eject.html